# How to properly store array inside of a Record

Tags: immutable.js

var z = Record({a: []});

```
var a = new z({a: [1]});
var b = new z({a: [1]});
expect(Immutable.is(a, b)).to.be.true; // false
```

This returns **false** because **[]** is a mutable structure. So I've changed that code into this:

```
var z = Record({a: List()});

var a = new z({a: List([1])});
var b = new z({a: List([1])});
expect(Immutable.is(a, b)).to.be.true; // true
```

And it seems to work since **Immutable.List** is immutable. So is this the properly way of storing an array inside of a Record?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
`int A[] = new int[5];` //creates the "A" array with an integer datatype
`int B[] = new int[5];` //creates the "B" array with an integer datatype
```

Would be the correct syntax. You can drop the `expect(Immutable.is(a, b)).to.be.true; // true`

You are probably getting an error because there is no data type in the syntax you provided above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Renan, was this answer helpful?